# Help understanding and visualizing the data from EEG grasp dataset from kaggle

Tags: eeg, data, visualization, brain-computer-interface

So, I downloaded the [EEG grasp data set](https://www.kaggle.com/c/grasp-and-lift-eeg-detection/data) from kaggle. I am having a hard time understanding the data and plotting it. I extracted the " first subjects' " csv files from the train folder which consists of 2 files - data and events. The events has the 6 events (as the columns) and has binary values for whether the event happened or not.

I am having trouble understanding the data file, which consists of 32 columns representing electrode channels and over a 100k rows. Each row consisting of integral values which I think is the digitized amplitude (please correct me if I'm wrong); In the data set what are "series"and what are the 100k+ rows in each series?

Also to understand how the data works, I need to visualize it - which I have no idea on how to plot using matplotlib library (I am using python 3), I know that the x axis should be time, but what do I put on the y axis when having a data set of 32 columns

PS - I don't want to use any advanced libs/softwares like EEGLAB, mne..etc.

Comment: Please post samples of the data and specifically indicate what the problem is (clearly show the 'series' and the columns and the 100k+ etc etc).

Comment: Did you view the paper that goes with the data? https://www.nature.com/articles/sdata201447.pdf It's always important to review all the information you have about a data set, especially when it isn't yours.

Comment: I did not, didn't think it was necessary. After reading it, I was able to understand the data-set much better. Thanks.